# Tried to get windows 8 developer license but got error 0x80004005

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I retrieved the windows 8 developer license on my laptop successfully. But when I tried to retrieve another one from another windows located in VirtualBox I got an error message said

[Content]
Error 0x80004005: Unspecified error

Something different on this windows 8 virtual machine:

1. It is running as a virtual machine.
2. It communicate to internet through CNTLM on my host machine (windows 7). But I had set the IE proxy, devenv.exe.config proxy as well as the PowerShell proxy.
3. I logged in this windows 8 with a local account while my laptop was logged as my windows account.

Can anyone give me some suggestion?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Working under a proxy I stumbled on the same error. I managed to activate VS developer license by doing the following:

1 - On Windows 8 Start search for Services (under settings)

2 - After that stop Network Location Awareness

3 - Try to activate again and you will be prompted a live ID request.

I got the solution from: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/toolsforwinapps/thread/112c6b04-9eda-49f2-95d8-62e0a169f99e/

Comment: I'm having Windows 8 and Visual Studio 2012.

I'm having same problem but when I try to stop "Network Location Awareness" from the services it restart automatically. I mean I stopped it and then I refresh the service list it shows the running status.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I commonly change networks and the auto-detect options for my proxy weren't working when I was on a network that wasn't behind a proxy. When I manually turned off the proxy settings I could then get the prompt for a live sign-on.